# complex model form binding with form elements being added to the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 models that I use to bind to a form. the models are as follows

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildModel> children { get; set;}
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GrandchildModel> grandchildren { get; set;}
}

public class GrandchildModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now what needs to happen is the user comes in to create the parent, clicks on the add child button that creates a textbox and a button then for everyone created one you have the option to create an grandchild. now binding this to the model is the problem im faced with.

Comment: When you say binding this to the model, are you talking about your viewmodel? the one yo pass to the view?

Comment: Jip the viewmodel finally figured this out after hacking away at it. Think my understanding was lacking abit